# Less intrusive way to capture CPU usage on Linux

Tags: linux, cpu-usage

How does a tool like **[Net-SNMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net-SNMP)** captures CPU usage?

And what would be the least intrusive way to do it under Linux?

*Less intrusive in the way that doing so would consume the least amount of machine resources (both cpu and ram) in order to do it. Eventually the data will be saved into a file.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no other way to calculate the current CPU utilization than reading `/proc` except for the kernel itself. All common tools like *ps*, *top* etc. are also just reading `/proc`, either `/proc/stat` for an overall CPU usage or `/proc/<pid>/stat` for a per-process CPU usage. However as `/proc`  is a virtual file system directly provided by the kernel the overhead for reading files in it is way smaller than for regular files.

If you don't want to read `/proc` yourself try to use a tool that does only little extra computations, like `ps` as mentioned by @deep.

Comment: Great answer! Full of detail and straight to the point! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using the $top command?

in fact, here is a list of methods including the $top one, try these :)

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-find-out-linux-cpu-utilization.html

Comment: Thks, sure! Both top, dstat, /proc/cpu... I'm not looking for a way to do it. I'm hopping that someone knows the **less intrusive** way of doing it (and top certainly isn't).

Comment: Ok, sorry don't worry then, teaches me to half read questions :P

Comment: @Frankie: What exactly is intrusive about reading `/proc`? That's its purpose.

Comment: what is the definition of less intrusive?

Comment: @Frankie A less intrusive way would be to write your own `top` but just that it samples `/proc` at a lower rate than the original `top`. You would lose accuracy of course but you need to draw the line somewhere

Comment: So I can assume that `Net-SNMP` just does some `cat` and `awk` on `/proc` and saves it into a file at a pre-defined pooling rate? @Satish will update the question to define less-intrusive.

Comment: @PavanManjunath top has a configurable _delay_ between intervals. However it does a little bit more than just calculating CPU usage.

Comment: @scai top does way way more and it's intensive (CPU wise).

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
ps -eo pcpu,pid | less
```

This will show the CPU usage along with the PIDs

Comment: Thks @deep! Unfortunately `ps` seams to read from `/proc` so it's still more efficient-wise to read from proc than to use `ps`, as seen here: http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_ps.htm

Comment: As already stated all those tools have to read from `/proc` as `/proc` is the only information source for this. So there can't be any more efficient tool than reading directly from `/proc`. However reading from `/proc` is really cheap as there is no real IO involved.

Comment: I think there is no other way to get CPU utilization other than reading from /proc except for diving into linux internals, which i am not sure of how to do.

Comment: @scai, please put that into an answer... for extra points give some hints as to the reason where there are no IO involved and the answer is yours.