# unable to capture top command output in a file using watch command

Tags: linux

I'm trying to write the output of a `top` command to a file, but it's not working.

Command I am trying:

```
watch -n 5 'top -p 4448 > /directorypath/filename.txt'
```

If I run only the `top` command without `watch` it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to write the output of top in a file and add it in cron so that i can get the output in a file after every time interval>>

script:

## !/bin/bash

top -b -n 5 -u mysql >> top.txt

crontab entry:

*/1 * * * * cd /scriptpath && sh script.sh

sample output:

top - 17:31:01 up 5 days,  5:59,  3 users,  load average: 0.42, 0.38, 0.40
Tasks: 193 total,   1 running, 190 sleeping,   1 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s): 19.6%us,  0.6%sy,  0.0%ni, 78.9%id,  0.3%wa,  0.1%hi,  0.5%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  24686168k total, 24549032k used,   137136k free,   663424k buffers
Swap: 12289716k total,      140k used, 12289576k free, 19292760k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
3259 mysql     15   0 3967m 3.5g 6372 S 52.9 14.9   3382:39 mysqld

top - 17:31:04 up 5 days,  5:59,  3 users,  load average: 0.47, 0.39, 0.41
Tasks: 192 total,   1 running, 189 sleeping,   1 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s):  4.5%us,  2.5%sy,  0.0%ni, 89.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.6%hi,  2.8%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  24686168k total, 24549520k used,   136648k free,   663424k buffers
Swap: 12289716k total,      140k used, 12289576k free, 19292772k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
3259 mysql     15   0 3967m 3.5g 6372 S 64.1 14.9   3382:41 mysqld

top - 17:31:07 up 5 days,  5:59,  3 users,  load average: 0.47, 0.39, 0.41
Tasks: 192 total,   1 running, 189 sleeping,   1 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s):  4.0%us,  1.8%sy,  0.0%ni, 91.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.5%hi,  2.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  24686168k total, 24549256k used,   136912k free,   663428k buffers
Swap: 12289716k total,      140k used, 12289576k free, 19292772k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
3259 mysql     15   0 3967m 3.5g 6372 S 56.1 14.9   3382:43 mysqld

top - 17:31:10 up 5 days,  5:59,  3 users,  load average: 0.43, 0.39, 0.40
Tasks: 192 total,   1 running, 189 sleeping,   1 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s):  4.0%us,  2.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 90.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.5%hi,  2.5%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  24686168k total, 24549876k used,   136292k free,   663428k buffers
Swap: 12289716k total,      140k used, 12289576k free, 19292772k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
3259 mysql     15   0 3967m 3.5g 6372 S 56.8 14.9   3382:44 mysqld

top - 17:31:13 up 5 days,  5:59,  3 users,  load average: 0.40, 0.38, 0.40
Tasks: 192 total,   1 running, 189 sleeping,   1 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s):  4.0%us,  2.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 91.2%id,  0.0%wa,  0.5%hi,  2.2%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  24686168k total, 24549876k used,   136292k free,   663436k buffers
Swap: 12289716k total,      140k used, 12289576k free, 19292772k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
3259 mysql     15   0 3967m 3.5g 6372 S 54.8 14.9   3382:46 mysqld

Comment: -b runs the top in batch mode which is useful in writing the output in a file

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want:

```
watch -n 5 'sh -c "top -p 4448 >> /p/a/t/h"'
```

but neither `watch` nor `top` are appropriate for non-interactive use.  In the comments, you indicate that you just want cpu usage, in which case you should do:

```
while ps -o %cpu= -p 4448; do sleep 5; done >> /p/a/t/h
```

Comment: ran and observed >>  sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
                                                             sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: There was a brief period during which I had omitted the trailing double quote.  Perhaps you ran it before I made the edit.

Comment: Hi, observed the following while running the edited command >> [root@verzcore1 ~]# watch -n 5 'sh -c "top -p 4448 >> /seachange/stackoverflow.txt"'
        top: failed tty get

Comment: try `date` instead of `top`, although this works as written for me.

Comment: watch -n 5 'sh -c "date -p 4448 >> /seachange/stachoverflow.txt"'
date: invalid option -- p
                         Try `date --help' for more information.  Is there anything wrong with the syntax??

Comment: Date does not take `-p`.  I was suggesting `watch 'sh -c "date > /path"'.  But you really don't want to store the output of `top` like this anyway.  `top` is designed for interactive use.  What information are you actually looking for?  There are probably better ways to get it.

Comment: i was trying to store the CPU utilization of the PID 4448 in a file. I thought top output can be stored in this way. Actually without watch i am able to store it. But after sometimes, the process gets stopped automatically for which i do not know the reason. Also tried to run the process in background like "top -p 4448 > /d/file.txt &", which doesn't work either

Comment: please suggest a suitable way to do the above operation. Ask me if any more details you want

Comment: If you just want cpu utilization, try `ps -p $PID -o %cpu=`.  eg: `watch -n 5 'sh -c "ps -p 4448 -o %cpu= >> /path"'`

Comment: But `watch` is also the wrong tool, since it is also designed for interactive use (it will write terminal formatting characters into the file).  You probably just want to do:  `while ps -p 4448 -o %cpu= >> /path; do sleep 5; done`

Comment: Added "while ps -p 4448 -o %cpu= >> /path; do sleep 5; done" in a script and when run returns similar to the other trials. Th efile is empty

Comment: Did i executed properly? or any mistakes i did while doing the above operation

Comment: Are you sure the pid is still 4448?  What does the command display when you run it at an interactive prompt and do not redirect the output?

Comment: [root@verzapp1 backup]# ps -p 16154
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
16154 ?        09:05:15 mysqld
But this is not showing CPU usage rt?

Comment: Hi, what about the way as mentioned as in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093924/less-intrusive-way-to-capture-cpu-usage-on-linux

Comment: when i run i am seeing the o/p as 16154 (mysqld) S 15913 15877 8788 0 -1 4202752 1750487 0 0 0 3257628 27890 0 0 15 0 25 0 184054275 4028297216 238382 18446744073709551615 4194304 11865200 140733953045872 18446744073709551615 230031148226 0 552967 4102 26345 18446744073709551615 0 0 17 2 0 0 0. But i am not sure which one is CPU usage data here. Can you help me on that?

Comment: `ps -p 16154` is not the same as `ps -p 16154 -o %cpu=`

Comment: I guess its not printing the CPU utilization of the provided PID                 [root@verzapp1 ~]# ps -p 11679 -o %cpu=
 4.9
[root@verzapp1 ~]# ps -p 11679 -o %cpu= All values look alike, But i could see those values changing in each iteration
 4.9
[root@verzapp1 ~]# ps -p 11679 -o %cpu=
 4.9
[root@verzapp1 ~]# ps -p 11679 -o %cpu=
 4.9
[root@verzapp1 ~]# ps -p 11679 -o %cpu=
 4.9
[root@verzapp1 ~]# ps -p 11679 -o %cpu=
 4.9
[root@verzapp1 ~]# ps -p 11679 -o %cpu=
 4.9
[root@verzapp1 ~]# ps -p 11679 -o %cpu=

Comment: Tried running this in script>> #!/bin/bash
echo $(date >> /seachange/top.txt)
top -n 1 -u mysql >> /seachange/top.txt  ............. It works fine ehwn run manually. But when added in cron only date is printing. But top output is not avaibalbe

Comment: Because `top` is designed for interactive use, and it works directly with the tty.  Run an strace on top and search for 'tty' in the result.

Comment: what if i write something like this: 
while [ 1 ]
do
  top -u mysql > filename.txt
  sleep 5
done